# Neo4J (Cypher): I want to create x nodes which are all bidirectionally connected with a single parent node all at once, how can I do that?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the Neo4J graph database and its proprietary language Cypher. I've delved in to doing so by attempting to shape this made out ontology of the city that I live in.
The basic premise of this topic is that I'd like to associate 100 nodes with a "parent" note.
The 100 "child" nodes would be the street numbers, while the one node to which they all would be connected to is the node of the street's name itself.
I'm not an expert programmer, quite far from it as is probably apparent.
I only know Python, somewhat, so the following code is the best I've got to exemplify what it is exactly that I want:

```
MATCH (s:Street{name:"Street_in_question"})
MATCH (n) WHERE (n)-[:STREET_NUMBER]->(s)
RETURN
CASE n.name
m = count(n.name)
WHEN m < 20
CREATE (sn:Street_Number{address:m})-[:STREET_NUMBER]->(s)
m + 1
```

So, now that you hopefully understand my aim, could you point me in the right direction?

Edit: 
This is the entire code with an attempted implementation of Mastisa's suggestion bellow.

```
CREATE (d:Country{name:"Croatia"})
CREATE (z:County{name:"Grad Zagreb"})-[:COUNTY_OF_COUNTRY]->(d)
CREATE (d)-[:COUNTRY_OF]->(z)
CREATE (g:City{name:"Zagreb"})-[:CITY_OF]->(z)
CREATE (z)-[:COUNTY_OF_CITY]->(g)
CREATE (k:Neighbourhood{name:"Savica"})-[s:NEIGHBOURHOOD_OF_CITY]->(g)
CREATE (g)-[:CITY_OF_NEIGHBOURHOOD]->(k)
CREATE (gruska:Street{name:"Gruška"})-[:STREET_OF_NEIGHBOURHOOD]->(k)
CREATE (k)-[:NEIGHBOURHOOD_OF_STREET]->(gruska)
WITH RANGE(1, 20) as list
UNWIND list as child_number
CREATE(n:Street_Number {number:child_number})
WITH n MATCH (gruska)
CREATE (n)-[:ST_NUMBER]->(gruska)
CREATE (gruska)-[:NUMBER_OF_STREET]->(n)
RETURN n, gruska
```

It connects every created node bidirectionally to **everything**, even themselves.

Comment: Connecting every node to every node even itself with ST_NUMBER, NUMBER_OF_STREET relationshs, is because of 13 line. **MATCH (gruska)** gruska will be every node in your db. You need to add node label and where in this line to filter unrelevant nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WITH` and `RANGE`, hope bellow cypher query can help you.

```
CREATE (n:Father)
UNWIND RANGE(1, 20) as child_number
CREATE(n:Child {name: 'CHILD '+child_number })
WITH n MATCH (f:Father)
CREATE (n)-[:CHILD_OF]->(f)
RETURN n, f
```

**Output:**

[image: Created graph]

Comment: You don't need the WITH, you can just do `UNWIND RANGE(1, 20) as list`

Comment: I'm not succeeding with your suggestion..
[link](http://prntscr.com/kvt6mr)
That's with the range reduced to 2.
I got 1000 relations created as a result of having performed what I think is an implementation of you code.
I'll add the whole code to the OP.